# The instance member 'key' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

So basically I got an error that says
**The instance member 'key' can't be accessed in an initializer.
Try replacing the reference to the instance member with a different expression** when I try to make a `StatefulWidget` as shown below

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  UserData userData;
  UserPage(this.userData) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _UserPageState(userData);
}
```

any solution for this one?
I tried to add 'late' at every point but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your `UserPage` constructor attempts to invoke the superclass constructor with `key` as an argument.  However, where do you expect `key` to come from?  From the base class itself?  Your `UserPage` constructor should have its own `key` parameter so that it can forward it.

Comment: @jamesdlin tis actually my first time using flutter, I don't really get what you're saying but if the parameter you're talking about for key, maybe this one? `MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => UserPage(userData),),`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do something like this:

```
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const UserPage({required this.userData, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final UserData userData;

  @override
  State<UserPage> createState() => _UserPageState();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `key` param is not always required. So you can just delete the `super` part.

```dart
class UserPage extends StatefulWidget {
  UserData userData;
  UserPage(this.userData);
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => new _UserPageState(userData);
}
```